# SonarQube starting Failed

Tags: centos-7, elasticsearch

I installed SonarQube Version 7.9.1 on CentOS 7 and the service set to start with non root user. My `vm.max_map_count` is set to 262144.

```
sysctl vm.max_map_count
vm.max_map_count = 262144
```

Because of My SonarQube version I set the JDK in `Wrapper.conf` to

```
wrapper.java.command=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk/bin/java
```

My sonar.log is:

```
--> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2019.07.29 13:31:51 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube/temp
2019.07.29 13:31:51 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2019.07.29 13:31:51 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch]: /opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
2019.07.29 13:31:51 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
2019.07.29 13:31:51 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2019.07.29 13:31:51 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65535]
2019.07.29 13:31:56 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [es]: 78
2019.07.29 13:31:56 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped
2019.07.29 13:31:56 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

My es.log is:

```
2019.07.29 13:31:53 INFO  es[][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (rootfs)]], net usable_space [31.1gb], net total_space [49.9gb], types [rootfs]
2019.07.29 13:31:53 INFO  es[][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment] heap size [494.9mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
2019.07.29 13:31:53 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] node name [sonarqube], node ID [XhVUvjLfTS-JwFuXmFVL4Q]
2019.07.29 13:31:53 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] version[6.8.0], pid[60694], build[default/tar/65b6179/2019-05-15T20:06:13.172855Z], OS[Linux/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/amd64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/11.0.4/11.0.4+11-LTS]
2019.07.29 13:31:53 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] JVM arguments [-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60, -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonarqube/temp, -XX:ErrorFile=../logs/es_hs_err_pid%p.log, -Des.enforce.bootstrap.checks=true, -Xms512m, -Xmx512m, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Des.path.home=/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch, -Des.path.conf=/opt/sonarqube/temp/conf/es, -Des.distribution.flavor=default, -Des.distribution.type=tar]
2019.07.29 13:31:53 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [analysis-common]
2019.07.29 13:31:53 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [lang-painless]
2019.07.29 13:31:53 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [mapper-extras]
2019.07.29 13:31:53 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [parent-join]
2019.07.29 13:31:53 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [percolator]
2019.07.29 13:31:53 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [reindex]
2019.07.29 13:31:53 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [repository-url]
2019.07.29 13:31:53 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [transport-netty4]
2019.07.29 13:31:53 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no plugins loaded
2019.07.29 13:31:54 WARN  es[][o.e.d.c.s.Settings] [http.enabled] setting was deprecated in Elasticsearch and will be removed in a future release! See the breaking changes documentation for the next major version.
2019.07.29 13:31:55 INFO  es[][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule] using discovery type [zen] and host providers [settings]
2019.07.29 13:31:55 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] initialized
2019.07.29 13:31:55 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] starting ...
2019.07.29 13:31:56 INFO  es[][o.e.t.TransportService] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9001}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9001}
2019.07.29 13:31:56 INFO  es[][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks] explicitly enforcing bootstrap checks
2019.07.29 13:31:56 ERROR es[][o.e.b.Bootstrap] node validation exception
[1] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65535]
2019.07.29 13:31:56 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] stopping ...
2019.07.29 13:31:56 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] stopped
2019.07.29 13:31:56 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] closing ...
2019.07.29 13:31:56 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] closed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To apply these configuration permanently, edit `/etc/sysctl.d/99-sonarqube.conf` or `/etc/sysctl.conf` and add:

```
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
sysctl -w fs.file-max=65536
ulimit -n 65536
ulimit -u 2048`
```

`vm.max_map_count` is greater or equals to 262144
`fs.file-max` is greater or equals to 65536
the user running SonarQube can open at least `65536 file descriptors`
the user running SonarQube can open at least `2048 threads`

Or if you want to apply these settings on `current session`, just enter each command in terminal:

```
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
sysctl -w fs.file-max=65536
ulimit -n 65536
ulimit -u 2048
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Commands are not permanent, I changed it in files and it works fine, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error yesterday and resolved it by following a short chain of resources.

1. Googling the `max file descriptors [4096]` issue identified [this top post](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/warnings-after-installation-of-sonarqube-developer-7-3/2430/12) . The solution highlighted the fact that it wasn't that `vm.max_map_count` variable wasn't being picked up correctly, but instead the `LimitNOFILE` and `LimitNPROC`. This post points the solution as updating variables in the "unit file".
2. After Googling around more for the commenter's mentioned "unit file", systemd, and updated documentation, [I found it here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/operate-server/#header-3) in the "Running SonarQube as a Service on Linux with SystemD" section.
3. By creating and running SonarQube via SystemD, it ensured the `max file descriptor` variables were actually being set. Following those exact directions allowed SonarQube to start without a problem.

Comment: Where I should set `vm.max_map_count` in CentOS 7? there are multiple place that mentioned in [link](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/warnings-after-installation-of-sonarqube-developer-7-3/2430/12)

Comment: I believe your main issue is the `max file descriptors [4096]`. I followed the official directions mentioned in the [second link](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/operate-server/#header-3) section "Running SonarQube as a Service on Linux with SystemD". This ensured that the max file descriptors was actually set.

You'll see in the sample `/etc/systemd/system/sonarqube.service` file, they set the `LimitNOFILE` variable, which based on your error logs.

Comment: I had a problem with my Postgres database, another problem is `vm.max_map_count`, when I set it with `sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144`, SonarQube run and it is accessible, but after restarting, again it should be set manually and I think `LimitNOFILE=65536
LimitNPROC=8192` in service file is not enough.